# How to use fs to write import and export statement

Tags: javascript, typescript, fs

So, I was doing for a fun project of building a code automation script.

To start with basic, I imported a bunch of images (.png file).

I have a habit of structuring my code like this.

```
|-Profile 
| -- image1.png
| -- image2.png
| -- index.ts
```

Where `index.ts` file would contain all the exports and import statement

```
export {default as image1} from './image1.png'
export {default as image2} from './image2.png'
```

So that I can import everything in just one statement (instead of writing multiple statements)

```
import {image1, image2} from '@src/profile'
```

To simply what I want to do, Consider I have a folder with a bunch of images, I want to create a script that read all the files in the folder and automatically add import and export statement.

I know how to create json file using fs which contains file name with format but I am not sure how to create a ts file and add all those export statements

This is my current script (to generate json)

```
/requiring path and fs modules
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');
//joining path of directory 

const directoryPath = path.join(__dirname, '/src/assests/images/avatars');

const imageData = []

//passsing directoryPath and callback function
fs.readdir(directoryPath, function (err, files) {
    //handling error
    if (err) {
        return console.log('Unable to scan directory: ' + err);
    } 
    //listing all files using forEach
    files.forEach(function (file) {
        // Do whatever you want to do with the file
        if (file.indexOf("@") == -1 && file !== ".DS_Store") {
        const fileInfo = file.split('.')
           const imageDetails = {
               name: fileInfo[0],
               format:fileInfo[1]
           }
            imageData.push(imageDetails)
        }
    });
    fs.writeFileSync('./src/assests/images/avatars/index.json', JSON.stringify(
       [...imageData]
    , null, 4))
});
```

Can someone help me in figuring out how to create a ts file and write `import` and `export` statements in it

example output

```
export {default as image1} from './image1.png'
export {default as image2} from './image2.png'
```

Comment: maybe add an exapmle of the intended output / contents?

Comment: There's nothing special about `.ts` files. It's just text. Format each line as a string, one for each file from the directory, and write them to `index.ts`.

Comment: As @Bergi says; if you know how to create and write a JSON file, you have everything you need to create a `.ts` file - it's just a text file with a specific extension

Answer (score 1):

Your script can be adapted easily because writing a ts file is like writing a json one. Those only contain text.

```
//requiring path and fs modules
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');

//joining path of directory 
const directoryPath = path.join(__dirname, '/src/assests/images/avatars');

//passsing directoryPath and callback function
fs.readdir(directoryPath, function (err, files) {
    //handling error
    if (err) {
        return console.log('Unable to scan directory: ' + err);
    } 
    // Creating file content.
    const fileContent = files.map(function (file) {
        // Do whatever you want to do with the file
        if (file.indexOf("@") == -1 && file !== ".DS_Store") {
           const [fileName, fileFormat] = file.split('.');
           return { name: fileName, format: fileFormat };
        }
        return {};
    })
        .filter((fileData) => fileData.format === 'png')
        .map((fileData) => `export { default as ${fileData.name} } from './${fileData.name}.${fileData.format}'`)
        .join('\n');

    fs.writeFileSync(`${directoryPath}/index.ts`, fileContent, null, 4))
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The following answer only includes the generating of the code, not any fs operations:

```js
const generate = (...files) => files
  .map(name => `export { default as ${name} } from './${name}.png'\n`)
  .join('')
  
console.log(generate('image1', 'image2', 'image3'))
```